# Decomposition of Lebesgue Measurable Function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm wondering if it is true that given a Lebesgue measurable function $f$ on a set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and a decomposition of $E$ into a finite collection of measurable sets, say $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{k}$, must $f$ be measurable on each $E_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it must. Let $A$ be a measurable subset of the codomain of $f$. Then

$$f\vert_{E_n}^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(A)\cap E_n.$$

And since $f$ is measurable, both sets on the right are measurable, and their intersection is then measurable as well. And so $f\vert_{E_n}$ is measurable.